# Slow writing in Redis version 3.2.4

Tags: redis

We are working with different redis versions and seen big difference in the time that takes to write data.

We've made a test writing 1 HMGets with 25000 keys 2 different versions of redis:

```
version 3.2.4 redis = 295 ms      version 3.0.2 redis = 299 ms      Fast version --> 3.2.4
version 3.2.4 redis = 282 ms      version 3.0.2 redis = 272 ms      Fast version --> 3.0.2
version 3.2.4 redis = 311 ms      version 3.0.2 redis = 277 ms      Fast version --> 3.0.2
version 3.2.4 redis = 275 ms      version 3.0.2 redis = 271 ms      Fast version --> 3.0.2
version 3.2.4 redis = 276 ms      version 3.0.2 redis = 610 ms      Fast version --> 3.2.4
version 3.2.4 redis = 3032 ms     version 3.0.2 redis = 261 ms      Fast version --> 3.0.2
version 3.2.4 redis = 1753 ms     version 3.0.2 redis = 257 ms      Fast version --> 3.0.2
version 3.2.4 redis = 908 ms      version 3.0.2 redis = 251 ms      Fast version --> 3.0.2
version 3.2.4 redis = 616 ms      version 3.0.2 redis = 257 ms      Fast version --> 3.0.2
version 3.2.4 redis = 491 ms      version 3.0.2 redis = 1281 ms     Fast version --> 3.2.4
version 3.2.4 redis = 445 ms      version 3.0.2 redis = 273 ms      Fast version --> 3.0.2
version 3.2.4 redis = 410 ms      version 3.0.2 redis = 270 ms      Fast version --> 3.0.2
version 3.2.4 redis = 369 ms      version 3.0.2 redis = 277 ms      Fast version --> 3.0.2
version 3.2.4 redis = 362 ms      version 3.0.2 redis = 263 ms      Fast version --> 3.0.2
version 3.2.4 redis = 4114 ms     version 3.0.2 redis = 1302 ms     Fast version --> 3.0.2
version 3.2.4 redis = 901 ms      version 3.0.2 redis = 282 ms      Fast version --> 3.0.2
version 3.2.4 redis = 593 ms      version 3.0.2 redis = 272 ms      Fast version --> 3.0.2
version 3.2.4 redis = 488 ms      version 3.0.2 redis = 266 ms      Fast version --> 3.0.2
version 3.2.4 redis = 4109 ms     version 3.0.2 redis = 1296 ms     Fast version --> 3.0.2
version 3.2.4 redis = 3996 ms     version 3.0.2 redis = 284 ms      Fast version --> 3.0.2
version 3.2.4 redis = 14793 ms    version 3.0.2 redis = 286 ms      Fast version --> 3.0.2
```

Has someone notice this increment when writing in redis? What is the reason for this?

Thank you.

Comment: Could you expand on what your results mean and how you tested?

Comment: The tests I made was creating one structure with one redis Key and 25000 Hash keys and values. Then I write this structure to two different versions of redis 50 times. The results I posted is the time that takes to write this structure in ms for the 2 different redis versions. In the last column I print wich has been faster writing.